# My actives are not going on cooldown?

Tags: league-of-legends

For some reasons no cooldown items go on cooldown when I hit assigned the hotkey. I noticed
that my potion and wards do go off, but items like blade of the ruined king, hextech gunblade, etc. are not going, when I try to use their active. I am using smart cast by the way. But this just started happening recently so I don't think it's smart casting that is affecting my problem.

Comment: are they working, and then not visibly showing that they are on cooldown or are they failing to work entirely

Comment: well i see them in my inventory and when i click the hotkey nothing happens but i discovered that the cooldown for tiamat and hydra are working so i am guessing its just hextech and botrk idk

Comment: Sounds like an issue with targeted actives.

Comment: youre right shelby

Comment: i really don't want to offend you, but do you know that you need to hover over an enemy with your cursor to activate them?

Comment: and to complete DropDeadSander - EUW , you need to be in range too, as BotRK and Hextech have both a small weird range, that might be the problem.

Comment: Are your items grey in the inventory? Because if they are I might answer to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug. Items that have an active on a champion (such as DFG active, Face of the Mountain active, and bork), sometimes do not activate on smart cast.

A temporary fix would have to be clicking the target, sorry.

Comment: Do you mean that sometimes, the smart cast items don't activate when pressed with the key?

Comment: @dyesdyes Yes .

Comment: That would explain some of my deaths...